# get_posts orderby='author' not working, looking for an alternative

Tags: wordpress

This piece of code is returning the data sorted by ID, not author as requested, so I am trying to think of another way to approach it.

```
$args = array('posts_per_page' => '-1','order' => 'ASC', 'orderby' => 'author');
$cat_posts = get_posts($args);

foreach ($cat_posts as $cat_post) :
    if (!in_array($cat_post->post_author,$author_array)) {
        $author_array[] = $cat_post->post_author;
    }
endforeach;

foreach ($author_array as $author) :
    $auth = get_userdata($author)->display_name;
    $nicename = get_userdata($author)->user_nicename;
    $option = '<option value="/author/'.$nicename.'">';
    $option .= $auth;
    $option .= '</option>';
    echo $option;
endforeach;
```

Is there a way to search and sort via last_name using the usermeta=user_lastname?  Or any ideas on how to get this simple code to work.

Comment: Try author_name instead of author?

Comment: No, `'orderby' => 'author` is the correct parameter'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Feel free to try this :

```
$args = array('posts_per_page' => '-1','order' => 'ASC', 'orderby' => 'author');
$cat_posts = get_posts($args);
$options = array();

foreach ($cat_posts as $cat_post) :
    if (!in_array($cat_post->post_author,$author_array)) {
        $author_array[] = $cat_post->post_author;
    }
endforeach;

foreach ($author_array as $author) :
    $auth = get_userdata($author)->display_name;
    $nicename = get_userdata($author)->user_nicename;
    $lastname = get_userdata($author)->last_name;
    $options[ $lastname ][] = '<option value="/author/'.$nicename.'">' . $auth . '</option>';
endforeach;
ksort($options);
foreach ($options as $key => $option) {
    foreach( $option as $k => $v ){
      echo $v;
    }
}
```

Let me know if it works ;)

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks Jeffrey...  but this code is just outputting the last user

Comment: Edited the answer. Feel free to try. Thanks!

Comment: Great! No problem. Feel free to mark it as answer ;)